# How to remove heroku ssh keys that don't have a name

Tags: heroku, ssh-keys

The heroku docs mention how to remove ssh keys that have a name associated with them using *heroku keys:remove*:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

But I have managed to upload some keys that don't have a name and now can't find a way to delete them. The *heroku keys:remove* command expects a name to be specified.

Is there some other way to clear ssh keys associated with an account?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can always delete keys in the web interface on heroku. Or you use `heroku keys:remove` with the full public key (or even the first part of the public key)

```
$ heroku keys
=== my@email.com Keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC...gegfp2Jw==
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC...wZp2PJUw==
```

Two keys without names and I want to delete the second ending in 'Juw=='. To get the full key, use the -l flag.

```
$ heroku keys -l
=== my@email.com Keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAsH1GFnghrmFSQ+Dkg71VtYjkRJzlAdimXj9M7ELHCZom6A3e/9GefzvxosirTqiCbxNPaBXO/nX4ZHH/fT5L+YhmOhJ0FQDGhhCz3g3ElnG5+ve+Aj3adE3xY3FIdM9ZNKMth5ymgl+aBOIg7cJyBWVlL5wrMmayTpdUnVEhw0aiRrS4BegO+LZVZ+EO+IP+Jj3pXwZ4kUNnw82OY1+TWfVswwUdYAVFBRkSyptj50KbTGI8QeSJTviNwH8x76amkdZj1cbERUH3/1IUsGuVtYU8K3pcrZU/QySQo1/9HK2cM0zJgULnHuUgVSaZ3E1ivWAU6bk2YhXsGlgegfp2Jw==    
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA1dk18DdzLS2B3Ops3VODW+YA8Lj4LC+hF9cS2uiTRXDcQali7UMT3jXAx/F5aADWRO5F3jJrcl2w6wWj6xd0Fubx9eV77NBbdGAWmHngqg23bQtJlw3uzErn94n4zhvxW/0pMuD3/TZ1SNRaWlE/q8TELAJJ8vJt2k8IfHH7FLWUOxQa0VlhG3nxfaVHHY+rLcjNmdyjXVYiKdko91jTmsTlT4HIpADTptyfEt0orUKPFZT8/ZgPEHEeNWEqZLGdPHc+knXwW3b7YfCSeUesYGwESZmNTo7opeQ2YIueDNhTRsPkZbRXzM1Qu1y0uv8jQqj1Y0uSQGsjQQwZp2PJUw==
```

You don't need to use the full key (but you can) just enough of the string so that is unique.

```
$ heroku keys:remove AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA1dk18DdzLS2B3Ops3VODW
Removing AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA1dk18DdzLS2B3Ops3VODW SSH key... done
```

Success!

```
$ heroku keys
=== my@email.com Keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC...gegfp2Jw==
```

Comment: The keys without a name do not show up in the web interface, but using a unique key snippet from the command line works as specified, thanks.